# Why is this wrong? PMFs

Tags: probability-distributions

I was asked to find $P_{XY}(x,y)$ from the CDFs. I gave the answer as $P_{XY}(x,y)=F_{XY}(x,y)-F_{XY}(x-1,y-1)$. I was told that I was wrong. Can you please explain why?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know this happens..!! I lost my reputation. I don't want any new answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F_{XY}(x,y) +F_{XY}(x-1,y-1) - F_{XY}(x,y-1)-F_{XY}(x-1,y)  = P_{XY}(x,y)$

Draw a 2-D graph of this and you will understand.

Comment: Oh!! right ! Thanks. I missed that.